# How to separate different data types of values in a column in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have an Excel problem, and I hope everyone can help me with it. Thank you.

So I have a column as below full of phone numbers and full names:

*People had option to put their full names or just their phone numbers when joining a Zoom meeting.

| Full_Name | Department |
| --- | --- |
| 14044445555 | A |
| Bob Max | A |
| 16788889999 | B |
| Sarah Harrison | C |

How can I separate them into a table as below:

| First_Name | Last_Name | Phone_Number | Department |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | 14044445555 | A |
| Bob | Max |  | A |
|  |  | 16788889999 | B |
| Sarah | Harrison |  | C |

I have tried to use "Text to Columns", but it only worked with people who put their full names.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it by formulas only then add three columns before department. As per my below screenshot use formulas like

<kbd>B2</kbd>`=IF(ISNUMBER(A2),"",TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ", REPT(" ",100)),100)))`
<kbd>C2</kbd>`=IF(ISNUMBER(A2),"",TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ", REPT(" ",100)),100)))`
<kbd>D2</kbd>`=IF(ISNUMBER(A2),A2,"")`

Then drag down and across right as needed.

[image]